# Fsck says read block too short

Tags: linux, hard-drive, hardware-failure, ext3, fsck

Yesterday I left my Ubuntu laptop alone for a bit, and the power cable got knocked out, so the computer got shut down. Upon starting it up, it insisted on running fsck, which failed, asking me to run it manually. So I booted onto my minimal partition that I keep for this kind of stuff (it's got a Damn Small installation with some other recovery/backup tools) and ran fsck on the partition. Some ways in I started getting system errors of the type that usually accompany a hardware failure (which is odd, since the disk is three months old). I then took the disk out of the Linux box entirely, and used a Mac to fsck it. The system errors are gone, but it gave me the following three types of error:

`Error reading block * (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read) while getting next inode from scan.`

`Entry '*' in *some directory* (*) has deleted/unused inode *.`

`Block bitmap differences: *some long list of numbers*.`

Anyhow it finished, but warned me that

`********* WARNING: Filesystem still has errors *********`

so I'm running another fsck. What I want to know is: will a second fsck fix anything else? is there another way to fix these errors? and should I pull everything off and send the disk in for warranty?

Thanks in advance,

--Actorclavilis

Comment: Update: After the second fsck, it booted properly, but the kernel panicked a few hours later and the same thing happened on restart.

Comment: There is a tool, Palimpsest, which is included with Ubuntu in System>Administration and which is supposedly good at detecting bad disks. Some guys on the [Ubuntu fora](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1461434.html) have had a similar problem.